# Show records of a particular year in one page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "abcd";

$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $user, $password, $dbname);   
$sql="SELECT YEAR(date) as year from events GROUP BY year";
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,$sql));
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql);         
$eyear=$row2['year'];

$year="2017";

for ($counter = 1; $counter <=5; $counter++){
    echo'<p><a href="'.$eyear.'">'.$year.'</a></p>';
    $year--;
}

?>
```

I want to retrieve records of separate years and display results for a particular year in one page

Comment: So what is wrong is taking $year variable as array of years?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions , a GROUP BY clause is never going to be a sensible option. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: do you follow any tutorial  ?